# Web API How to Handle Dashes and DateTime Formating

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api

Using .Net Web API I have to write a service to consume some restful calls made by a third party to our server.  I have no control over the XML that we are sent and cannot change it in anyway.  We will only receive HTTP POST calls and they will all be in XML format.

Here is an example of an XML message that we will receive:

```
<listing-confirmation>
<account-id>123456</account-id>
<allow-bid>true</allow-bid>
<allow-both>true</allow-both>
<allow-buy>true</allow-buy>
<allow-offers>false</allow-offers>
<auction-work-order>1234</auction-work-order>
<bid-count>1</bid-count>
<bid-increment>50</bid-increment>
<buyer-group-name>og_name bg_name</buyer-group-name>
<buyer-group-type>GlobalOpen</buyer-group-type>
<buy-now-price>1000</buy-now-price>
<condition-report-url>some_url</condition-report-url>
<current-bid>700</current-bid>
<end-timestamp>Wed May 25 21:48:09 +0000 2011</end-timestamp>
<event-sale-id>1234</event-sale-id>
<event-sale-name>event_sale_name</event-sale-name>
<facilitated-auction-code>abc</facilitated-auction-code>
<floor-price>700</floor-price>
<listing-activated-timestamp>Tue May 24 21:38:09 +0000 2011</listing-activated-timestamp>
<manheim-group-code>mgc</manheim-group-code>
<physical-location>at_auction</physical-location>
<seller-id>5000000</seller-id>
<starting-bid-price>300</starting-bid-price>
<start-timestamp>Tue May 24 21:38:09 +0000 2011</start-timestamp>
<stock-number>3BBBDOC</stock-number>
<unique-bidder-count>1</unique-bidder-count>
<vehicle-detail-url>http://localhost/vdp/show/169</vehicle-detail-url>
<view-count>0</view-count>
<vin>12345678901234567</vin>
</listing-confirmation>
```

I have several questions:

1 - How do I handle the dash in the root XML message? Would it be like this

```
[XmlRoot("listing-confirmation")]
public class Listing_confirmation
```

2 - How do I handle the dashes in the xml elements? Would I use this

```
[XmlElement("account-id")]
public int account_id { get; set; }
```

3 - How do I handle the datetime formating? Will it automatically understand and convert it to a DateTime or do I need to do something to handle that? If so, how do I do that?

Thanks!
Jeremy

**EDIT AS OF 10/1/2012 @ 4:56 EST**

Here is my new Class file for my Listing_confirmation model

```
[DataContract(Name="listing-confirmation")]
public class Listing_confirmation
{
    [DataMember(Name="account-id")]
    public int account_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="allow-bid")]
    public bool allow_bid { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="allow-both")]
    public bool allow_both { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="allow-buy")]
    public bool allow_buy { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="allow-offers")]
    public bool allow_offers { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="auction-work-order")]
    public int? auction_work_order { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="bid-count")]
    public int? bid_count { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="bid-increment")]
    public int? bid_increment { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="buyer-group-name")]
    public string buyer_group_name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="buyer-group-type")]
    public string buyer_group_type { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="buy-now-price")]
    public int buy_now_price { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="condition-report-url")]
    public string condition_report_url { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="current-bid")]
    public int? current_bid { get; set; }
    //[DataMember(Name="end-timestamp")]
    //public DateTime end_timestamp { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="event-sale-id")]
    public int? event_sale_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="event-sale-name")]
    public string event_sale_name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="facilitated-auction-code")]
    public string facilitated_auction_code { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="floor-price")]
    public int floor_price { get; set; }
    //[DataMember(Name="listing-activated-timestamp")]
    //public DateTime listing_activated_timestamp { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="manheim-group-code")]
    public string manheim_group_code { get; set; }
    //[DataMember(Name="message-triggered")]
    //public DateTime message_triggered { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="physical-location")]
    public string physical_location { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="seller-id")]
    public int seller_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="starting-bid-price")]
    public int? starting_bid_price { get; set; }
    //[DataMember(Name="start-timestamp")]
    //public DateTime start_timestamp { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="stock-number")]
    public string stock_number { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="unique-bidder-count")]
    public int? unique_bidder_count { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="vehicle-detail-url")]
    public string vehicle_detail_url { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="view-count")]
    public int? view_count { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="vin")]
    public string vin { get; set; }
}
```

However, it still does not bind the data correctly.  When I debug the controller it always has ModelState.IsValid = false and the Listing_Confirmation object is always null.  Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about serializing XML into an object but I can help with the format string.  The format string you will use to parse the date is this..."ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", eg.  DateTime.ParseExact("Tue May 24 21:38:09 +0000 2011", "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How WebAPI does Parameter Binding Work](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx):

> There are 2 techniques for binding parameters: Model Binding and
>   Formatters. In practice, WebAPI uses model binding to read from the
>   query string and Formatters to read from the body.

If the XML you are receiving from the third party is in the body of the POST operation then you should write a custom XML media formatter to perform the model binding that will take the XML and return a .NET object that represents the data being received.

See [Media Formatters](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) for an example of how to write a custom media type formatter. You will need to replace the default XML media type formatter with your custom XML formatter.

Comment: It is not the response that I am worried about.  I am trying to get the request (POST) to convert properly into my object that I have created.  I have set UseXmlSerializer = true in my Application_Start() and I have also tried adding [XmlElement("account-id")] decorations and [DataMember(Name = "account-id")] decorations but have been unable to get the request to convert properly to my object.  The object is always NULL when I debug.

Comment: Ah, I see. That means the model binding isn't working. That means you need a custom formatter most likely.

Comment: Using this link: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#xml_media_type_formatter

Comment: It says "To change how the class name appears in the XML, set the Name parameter in the DataContract attribute." and then it also says "To change how a member name appears in the XML, set the Name parameter in the DataMember attribute."  So, I turned the UseXMLSerializer Off and then I added [DataContract(Name="listing-confirmation")]
    public class Listing_confirmation  and I also added [DataMember(Name="account-id")] to each property with the appropriate name but it is still not binding correctly.  When I go to debug it has the object as null.  Why doesn't it recognize the proper names?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem was.

1 - In my Application_Start() method I added the following lines of code to specify to use the XmlSerializer instead of the DataContract Serializer:

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

2 - I used the XmlRoot and XmlElement attributes to decorate the class name and each of the properties.  Here is my new class file -

```
[XmlRoot("listing-confirmation")]
public class Listing_confirmation
{
    [XmlElement("account-id")]
    public int account_id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("allow-bid")]
    public bool allow_bid { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("allow-both")]
    public bool allow_both { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("allow-buy")]
    public bool allow_buy { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("allow-offers")]
    public bool allow_offers { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("auction-work-order")]
    public int auction_work_order { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("bid-count")]
    public int bid_count { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("bid-increment")]
    public int bid_increment { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("buyer-group-name")]
    public string buyer_group_name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("buyer-group-type")]
    public string buyer_group_type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("buy-now-price")]
    public int buy_now_price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("condition-report-url")]
    public string condition_report_url { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("current-bid")]
    public int current_bid { get; set; }
    //[XmlElement("end-timestamp")]
    //public DateTime end_timestamp { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("event-sale-id")]
    public int event_sale_id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("event-sale-name")]
    public string event_sale_name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("facilitated-auction-code")]
    public string facilitated_auction_code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("floor-price")]
    public int floor_price { get; set; }
    //[XmlElement("listing-activated-timestamp")]
    //public DateTime listing_activated_timestamp { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("manheim-group-code")]
    public string manheim_group_code { get; set; }
    //[XmlElement("message-triggered")]
    //public DateTime message_triggered { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("physical-location")]
    public string physical_location { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("seller-id")]
    public int seller_id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("starting-bid-price")]
    public int starting_bid_price { get; set; }
    //[XmlElement("start-timestamp")]
    //public DateTime start_timestamp { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("stock-number")]
    public string stock_number { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("unique-bidder-count")]
    public int unique_bidder_count { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("vehicle-detail-url")]
    public string vehicle_detail_url { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("view-count")]
    public int view_count { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("vin")]
    public string vin { get; set; }
}
```

3 - I had to comment out all of my DateTime properties because it was not able to convert the values being passed into a valid DateTime.  I am still working on getting that working correctly.

Comment: You could create a custom date-time class that implements IXmlSerializable and handles the string format you are seeing; or you could just use a string property for the datetime elements and add utility getter properties to Listing_confirmation. E.g. the bound property is start_timestamp_value and you have a start_timestamp property that parses the value and returns a DateTime

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure out the DateTime formatting issue as well.  Here is an example of how I handled one DateTime.  I treated the others similarly.

```
[XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime? start_timestamp { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("start-timestamp")]
    public string start_timestampstring
    {
        get
        {
            return start_timestamp.HasValue ? start_timestamp.Value.ToString("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy") : string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                try
                {
                    start_timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
                catch
                {
                    start_timestamp = null;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                start_timestamp = null;
            }
        }
    }
```